# Combine strings into list in python

Tags: python

```
my_list = ['a','b','c']

new_item = 'd'
newest_item = 'e'
```

How can i get?

```
result = ['a','b','c','d','e']
```

My attempt was:

```
result = [x for x in my_list,new_item,newest_item]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>> result = my_list + [new_item, newest_item]
>> result
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

The `+` operator can be used to concatenate two lists. Note that this creates a new list `result` and thus preserves the original value of `my_list`.

Answer (score 2):

Along with @mdml's solution, you can also simply use `append`

```
>>> my_list = ['a','b','c']
>>> my_list.append('d')
>>> my_list
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> my_list.append('e')
>>> my_list
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

Comment: Or `.extend(('d', 'e'))`.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind altering your initial list (and avoid a copy):

```
>>> foo = [1,2,3,4]
>>> foo.extend([5,6])
>>> foo
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use so many ways to achieve this result.

First of, you can append items to your list:

```
my_list = ['a','b','c']
my_list.append('d') -> ['a','b','c','d']
my_list.append('e') -> ['a','b','c','d', 'e']
```

It is handy if you need to add items in cycle.

If you have few items and you want to add all of then to list:

```
my_list = ['a','b','c']
my_list.extend(['d', 'e']) -> ['a','b','c','d', 'e']
```

Or

```
my_list += ['d', 'e']
```